# Differentiation result question

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

$$\frac{d^{2n}(x^2-1)^{n}}{dx^{2n}}=(2n)!$$ I need this for one problem, but i dont know how to prove such thing , $\int_{-1}^{1}5\frac{d^{2n}(x^2-1)^{n}}{dx^{2n}}dx=(2n)!\int_{-1}^{1}5dx$

I tried doing this but i cant get $(2n)!$. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

$(X^2-1)^n$ is a polynomial of degreee $2n$, with first coefficient $1$. Thus, its $2n$ derivative is a constant polynomial, with coefficient $(2n)(2n-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1 = (2n)!$. It is because when you differentiate $X^{2n}$ you get $2nX^{2n-1}$,then $2n(2n-1)X^{2n-2}$, etc.

Comment: Can you write it in great detail? $(x^2-1)^{n}$ behaves as $x^{2n}$ and so we differentiate it 2n times or? Why dont we differentiate the entire expression $(x^2-1)^{n}$? If we differentiate the entire expression we get $2xn(x^2-1)^{n-1}$ and again we get more and more complex expression. Therefore we consider just $x^{2n}$ which is the leading one or ?

Comment: Write $(X-1)^{2n} = X^{2n} + Q(X)$ where $Q$ is a polynomial of degree $\leqslant 2n-1$. Differentiate $2n$ times this equality : you have $\frac{d^{2n}}{dX^{2n}}(X-1)^{2n} = (2n)! + Q^{(2n)}(X)$. As $Q$ is of degree $\leqslant 2n-1$, its $2n$th derivative vanishes, and you have your result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** $(x^2-1)^n$ is a polynomial of degree $2n$ whose dominant coefficient is $x^{2n}$.